# Azure DevOps conditions in parameters

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

Help me please with creating conditions in parameters in the step template.

I want to change parameters in the template depending on variable.Mode value.
For example, this code doesn't work:

```
  - template: ../templates/template1.yml
    parameters:
      ${{ if eq(variables.Mode, 'dev') }}:
        mode: dev
        namespace: dev-namespace
        fqdn: dev.mysite.com
      ${{ if eq(variables.Mode, 'staging') }}:
        mode: staging
        namespace: staging-namespace
        fqdn: staging.mysite.com
        anothervar: value
        yetanothervar: value2
```

The template executes with default values of parameters.
What can I do to set vars depending on variable.Mode value.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify different parameter values in stages. Here is my sample:

azure-pipelines.yml:

```
variables:
  Mode: dev

stages:
  - ${{ if eq(variables.Mode, 'dev') }}:
    - template: template.yml
      parameters:
        mode: dev
        namespace: dev-namespace
        fqdn: dev.mysite.com

  - ${{ if eq(variables.Mode, 'staging') }}:
    - template: template.yml  # Template reference
      parameters:
        mode: staging
        namespace: staging-namespace
        fqdn: staging.mysite.com
        anothervar: value
        yetanothervar: value2
```

template.yml:

```
parameters:
- name: mode  
  default: ''
- name: namespace
  default: ''
- name: fqdn
  default: ''
- name: anothervar 
  default: ''
- name: yetanothervar 
  default: ''

stages:
- stage: 
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
    - script: echo ${{ parameters.mode }}
```

Comment: I tried this syntax, but it seems like mode variable not defined.
And when pipeline starts, step with template is absent in steps list.
It sets as pipeline variable. When pipeline starts.

Comment: You can define mode variable in azure-pipelines.yml. You need to add this at the top of azure-pipelines.yml:variables:
  Mode: dev I add this part in my answer. You should be able to work well if you use my example above.

Comment: @Win32Sector Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if you're still blocked, I'll try my best to help :)